# Project in VS2010 unavailable and can't reload

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, sourcegear-vault, source-control-bindings

I've been trying to load a project from a SourceGear Vault Client that has a plug-in for Visual Studio 2010. After selecting the solution file, the solution explorer populates with the associated projects but appends `(unavailable)` to the end of each project name.

The usual remedy is to reload each unavailable project but in doing so briefly reveals all files within each project but then VS quickly hides them and makes the project unavailable again.

So far, I have tried opening the code in VS2015, removing all related source control information from the .csproj and .sln files, and deleting the associated .suo file. Nothing has worked yet and I have exhausted all the known fixes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to clean the solution then build all available projects which has all files that you can see. After that, try to reload those unavailable projects.

Comment: You could try running Visual Studio in safe mode to see if a 3rd party plugin is to blame: `devenv.exe /SafeMode`

Comment: Since everything is unavailable and I cannot open any code, VS will not give me the option to do a clean build.

Comment: Thanks @PeterRitchie for the adviced worked perfectly, now all I have to do is find the plugin at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I'm copying @PeterRitchie solution that worked for me, below.

> You could try running Visual Studio in safe mode to see if a 3rd party plugin is to blame: devenv.exe /SafeMode – Peter Ritchie